# Extract tags from xml document

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm trying to extract some tags from `XML` document using `JAVA` and I saw some answers related to `DOM` but I don't need the value of the tag, the following `XML` which I have to extract `<MsgHeader>` Tag

```
    <MFEP>
    <MsgHeader>
        <TmStp>2013-12-25T10:52:50</TmStp>
        <TrsInf>
            <SdrCode>145</SdrCode>
            <RcvCode>7777</RcvCode>
            <ReqTyp>asd</ReqTyp>
        </TrsInf>
    </MsgHeader>

    <MsgHeader>
        <TmStp>2013-12-25T10:52:50</TmStp>
        <TrsInf>
            <SdrCode>2123</SdrCode>
            <RcvCode>323</RcvCode>
            <ReqTyp>asd</ReqTyp>
        </TrsInf>
    </MsgHeader>

    <MsgBody>
        <AcctInfo>
            <BillingNo>asd</BillingNo>
            <BillNo>1267</BillNo>
        </AcctInfo>
        <ServiceType>FixedLine</ServiceType>
    </MsgBody>
    <MsgFooter>
        <Security>
            <Signature>asd</Signature>
        </Security>
    </MsgFooter>

    <MsgHeader>
        <TmStp>2013-12-25T10:52:50</TmStp>
        <TrsInf>
            <SdrCode>2</SdrCode>
            <RcvCode>3</RcvCode>
            <ReqTyp>BILPULRQ</ReqTyp>
        </TrsInf>
    </MsgHeader>
</MFEP>
```

And the output must be

```
    <MsgHeader>
        <TmStp>2013-12-25T10:52:50</TmStp>
        <TrsInf>
            <SdrCode>145</SdrCode>
            <RcvCode>7777</RcvCode>
            <ReqTyp>asd</ReqTyp>
        </TrsInf>
    </MsgHeader>

    <MsgHeader>
        <TmStp>2013-12-25T10:52:50</TmStp>
        <TrsInf>
            <SdrCode>2123</SdrCode>
            <RcvCode>323</RcvCode>
            <ReqTyp>asd</ReqTyp>
        </TrsInf>
    </MsgHeader>

    <MsgHeader>
        <TmStp>2013-12-25T10:52:50</TmStp>
        <TrsInf>
            <SdrCode>2</SdrCode>
            <RcvCode>3</RcvCode>
            <ReqTyp>BILPULRQ</ReqTyp>
        </TrsInf>
    </MsgHeader>
```

Comment: This would be easy with xslt

Comment: I worked little with XSLT before but unfortunately there is not time to learn more, if there is another idea would be better

Comment: Well, if you show us your Java code that selects the element nodes then we can add some code to serialize them, in general look into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html to serialize a node as XML. Or use the default Transformer.

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html for a start on how to write a DOM node out as XML.

Comment: You forgot to show us your code. You should explain what concrete problem you have.

Answer (score 2):

I know you are not willing to mess around XSLT, but it would be as simple as this:

transform.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <MFEP>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/MFEP/MsgHeader"/>
    </MFEP>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/MFEP/MsgHeader">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Java code:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform.xslt"));
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));
transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
```

Comment: Perfect it works, but what if i need it dynamic means it's not always have to be **/MFEP/MsgHeader** it might be other tags, so if I can pass the tag from java code ?

Comment: Usually it is easier /faster to change that directly on the xslt file, since you don't need to recompile and pack it in a jar/war file. If you have to cover many XML structures, you can write a xslt for each, and pass xslt file path as a Java argument.  If it's is not enough, you could pass parameters to the xslt file (transformer.setParameter()) , or even generate a xslt file programmatically, since it is a XML file itself. But I think you should consider the simpler options first.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll try, +1 Thanks